# How to undo deletion of CKRecord?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord

Does CloudKit provide any way to recover deleted `CKRecords`?

I would like to avoid setting flags for records and then provide a way to differentiate which of them were removed.

Comment: No, there is no undo.

Comment: No undo operation supported. You need your own local cache and your own "recovery" procedure.